# Getting error:"ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor". when connecting DJANGO to a remote oracle database

Tags: python, django, database, oracle

i can successfully connect to the remote database from my laptop through the follwing sqlplus command:

```
sqlplus pdb1admin/mypass@192.168.18.102:1521/pdb1
```

but when i enter the credentials in my django project it gives the error:"ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor".

my pluggable database name is pdb1. my service name is also pdb1. my username for the pdb1 database is pdb1admin. my password is 'mypass' and my port is 1521.

my settings.py file in django project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'pdb1',
        'USER': 'pdb1admin',
        'password':'mypass',
        'HOST':'192.168.18.102',
        'PORT':'1521',
    }
}
```

here is my tnsnames.ora file which is on my other computer which have the oracle database running.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.18.102)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
  
PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.18.102)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb1)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.18.102)(PORT = 1521))
  
LISTENER_PDB1 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.18.102)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

i can connect via terminal sqlplus so there must be something wrong with the credentials ?

Comment: Your easy connect string for SQL\*Plus ends with `/pdb1` so that is using service name `pdb1`, as is the entry in your tnsnames.ora. With your settings Django is treating that as the SID not the service name. The linked question shows several ways to make it work - removing host/port so it's treated as TNA alias, giving the full connection info in the name instead, etc.

Comment: @AlexPoole i tried the solution in the post that earlier but it was giving me error:"django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied"

Comment: 'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '192.168.18.102:1521/pdb1',
        'USER': 'pdb1admin',
        'password':'mypass',
    }

Comment: Does `'password'` just need to be `'PASSWORD'`?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes i capitalized it and it worked. Thank you so much.